# Dask DummyEncoder not returning all the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dask, one-hot-encoding

I tried using dask [DummyEncoder](http://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/generated/dask_ml.preprocessing.DummyEncoder.html) for `OneHotEncoding` my data. But the results are not as expected.

dask's DummyEncoder Example:

```
from dask_ml.preprocessing import DummyEncoder
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
                'B': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','c']
                    })
de = DummyEncoder()
de = de.fit(data)
testD = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['a','a']})
trans = de.transform(testD)
print(trans)
```

Ouput:

```
   B_a

0    1
1    1
```

Why it doesn't show `B_b`, `B_c`? But when I change the `testD` as this:

```
testD = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['a','a', 'b', 'c']})
```

Result is:

```
   B_a  B_b  B_c
0    1    0    0
1    1    0    0
2    0    1    0
3    0    0    1
```

sklearn's OneHotEncoder Example **(After LabelEncoding)**:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
                'B': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
})
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder = encoder.fit(data)
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'B': [2, 2]})
trans = encoder.transform(testdf).toarray()
pd.DataFrame(trans, columns=encoder.active_features_)
```

Output:

```
     1    2    3
0  0.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

How do I achieve the same results? The reason I want it this way because I will be encoding a subset of the columns and then concatenate the resultant encoded_df to the main df along with that dropping main column from the main df.

So something like below (main df):

```
   A  B   C
0  M  1  10
1  F  2  20
2  T  3  30
3  M  4  40
4  F  5  50
5  F  6  60
```

Expected output:

```
   A_F  A_M  A_T  B   C
0    0    1    0  1  10
1    1    0    0  2  20
2    0    0    1  3  30
3    0    1    0  4  40
4    1    0    0  5  50
5    1    0    0  6  60
```

EDIT:

Since dask internally uses pandas, I believe it uses `get_dummies`. Which is how `DummyEncoder` is behaving. If someone could point out a way to do the same in pandas will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From dask's documentation for `DummyEncoder` `columns` parameter:

> The columns to dummy encode. **Must be categorical dtype**. 
>      Dummy encodes all categorical dtype columns by default.

Also, it says [here](https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/blob/master/docs/source/preprocessing.rst#additional-tranformers) that you **must always** use a `Categorizer` before using some encoders (`DummyEncoder` included).

A correct way to do this:

```
from dask_ml.preprocessing import Categorizer, DummyEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

pipe = make_pipeline(
    Categorizer(), DummyEncoder())

pipe.fit(data)

pipe.transform(testD)
```

Which will ouput:

```
    B_a     B_b     B_c
0   1       0       0
1   1       0       0
```

Comment: I missed it, don't know how. Apologies.

Comment: @Asif no need to apologize. Glad I could help!